# trying to download a file from SFTP server but i get this error "could not find a part of the path "

Tags: c#, sftp

```
class program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const string host = "XXXX";
        const string username = "XXXX";
        const string password = "XXXX";
        const string workingdirectory = "/home/DRuser/Digital 
        River / Inbound / ";
        const string remotefile = "/home/DRuser/Digital 
        River / Inbound / Analysis
        for Production Fix Substring.csv ";
        const int port = XX;

        Console.WriteLine("Creating Client and Connecting");
        using(var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password)) {
            client.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to host");

            client.ChangeDirectory(workingdirectory);
            Console.WriteLine("Changed directory to {0}", workingdirectory);

            var listDirectory = client.ListDirectory(workingdirectory);
            Console.WriteLine("Listing directory:");
            foreach(var fi in listDirectory) {
                Console.WriteLine(" - " + fi.Name);
            }
            using(var file = File.OpenWrite(remotesite)) //download file from sftp to local
            {
                client.DownloadFile(remotefile, file);
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded");
            }
            client.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I successfully connect to the sftp server and loop through all 
the files in the respective directory but when i try to 
download them i get this error

> could not find a part of the path 'C:\home\DRuser\Digital River\Inbound\'.'
>   i get this error at the using (var file = File.OpenWrite(remotesite)) line of code.

how do i fix this ?

Comment: `File.OpenWrite` opens a file on the receiving system. But I think you are passing the path to a file on the sending system instead.

Comment: finally able to download thank you so much Georg, appreciate it!! cheers

Comment: @ArbaazKhan what changes you have done to download the file?